# Find specific unknown depth grandchildren in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking to find any root node that has a specific (great? great?) grand child at an unknown depth, that passes through multiple nodes and relationships of different types before it finally reaches the `ListItem` nodes that is always related to its parent with `HAS_SELECTED`.

I have tried both:

```
MATCH (r:Root)-[HAS_SELECTED*]->(l:ListItem {alias: 'test'})
RETURN r
```

and

```
MATCH (r:Root)-[HAS_SELECTED*]->(l:ListItem)
WHERE l.alias = 'test'
RETURN r
```

An example graph could be

```
r   r    r                r
    |    |                |
    c  ListItem           c
    |                     |
    c                     c
    |                     |
 ListItem(alias = test) ListItem(alias=somethingElse)
```

How would i find the `r` that ends up being related to the `ListItem` that has the alias of "test" without knowing all the intermediate relationships and nodes, or even how many intermediate relationships and nodes there may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (r:Root)-[*0..]->()-[:HAS_SELECTED]->(l:ListItem)
WHERE l.alias = 'test'
RETURN r
```

A [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) can use a zero lower bound to indicate that the relationship is optional. (When the relationship does not exist, the nodes on both sides of it in the pattern would actually correspond to the same node).

(Also, in a `MATCH` pattern you need to put a colon before a relationship type name.)